# How to work out the height of a point on a tilted surface?

Tags: physics, mathematics, rotation, trigonometry

I have a plane which gets tilted on the X and Z axis (y+ is the normal).

Given an X and Z coordinate and the X and Z rotation of the plane, how do I find out the height (Y) at that point?

I assume this is a trigonometry question... I could use simple sin & cos to work it out if it was moving on just the X or Z axis, but what if it's at 3,8 (x,z)? Maybe an average of the sin/cos heights?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your plane passes through the origin, then it can be defined in terms of its normal vector as the set of all points perpendicular to the normal, ie.

```
dot(position, normal) = 0
```

Here your normal is the object's local y-axis, `transform.up`.

So you want to find a coordinate triple `(x, y, z)` perpendicular to `transform.up`. We can solve:

```
dot((x, y, z), transform.up) = 0
y * transform.up.y + dot((x, 0, z), transform.up) = 0
y * transform.up.y = -dot((x, 0, z), transform.up)
y = (-x * transform.up.x - z * transform.up.z)/transform.up.y
```

And now we have an expression for `y` in terms of `x` & `z`, without using any transcendental functions, just ordinary multiplication subtraction and division. :)

Comment: THANK YOU @DMGregory!!! That is absolutely perfect and exactly what I need. I need to read up on how best to use the `dot()` command.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - looks like you just add them together!

```
float angX = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * transform.eulerAngles.z);
float angZ = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * transform.eulerAngles.x);

foreach(GameObject item in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Fart")) {
  float yx = fart.transform.position.x * angX;
  float yz = fart.transform.position.z * -angZ;
  item.transform.position = new Vector3(item.transform.position.x, (yx + yz), item.transform.position.z);
}
```

Comment: This looks a bit sketchy to me. Have you tried it with large angles? Some approximations hold decently well for shallow angles but blow up once the object tilts further.

Comment: You're right; in my case, as the item moves across the plane, this becomes less accurate. My plane only moves on a +/- 15 degree tilt, so it wasn't initially obvious.